# How to analyze an app's IPS file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to find out why my app is crashing for certain users. I personally cannot replicate it.

The user emailed me their IPS file. This is the output after I've loaded it in Organizer, and right clicked, selected Re-symbolicate:
http://pastebin.com/8q6RE7sU

I assume this is where the problem occurred in my code:

```
3   FlightMachine                       0x000000010003b970 0x100028000 + 80240
4   FlightMachine                       0x000000010008b79c 0x100028000 + 407452
```

But how do I find out what is at `0x100028000 + 80240`, to find out what the actual problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)

Comment: This is the output after I've loaded it in Organiser, and right clicked, selected Re-symbolicate. I updated my question to include this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `dsym` file of your app version which got crash, you can symbolicate it using `atos` tool with the steps [mentioned in Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: OMG finally I figured out why I couldn't import the crash log! iPhone exports crash logs with the extension .ips but you have to manually change that to .crash to be able to import it to the device logs in xcode!

Answer (score 20):

1. Rename the .ips file to .crash file
2. Open xcode -> Window -> Devices & Simulators
3. Connect any iOS device to Mac (even if you have the file on your mac)
4. View Device logs (this will show all device logs)
5. Select "All logs"
6. Drag and drop the .crash file you have
7. Right click and "re-symbolicate log"

You need to have either the xcarchive or dsym files in organizer relevant for the build in which you have the crash.
Refer [Apple docs to add dsym files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report)

Comment: This works legit. Couldn't thank you enough.

Comment: When I do this, nothing happens. Received ips file from App Review. After re-symbolicating, are there more steps?

Comment: that worked with me after rename .ips to .crash, and reopen device logs in Xcode

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, `Open recent logs` button (which replaced the `View device logs` in Xcode 14) just opens a file picker, and when I add the log there, it just opens un-symbolicated in xcode :/.

Answer (score 6):

For additional info, I opened Organiser, selected Download dSYMs, then went to Devices > View Error Logs, imported the IPS file into it (by drag and dropping). Then I right clicked the relevant crash and selected re-symbolicate.

If your IPS files dont simply drag into the crash view, rename them to .crash, then back again to IPS.