# iOS atos command - how do you find the load address in a hang report (.ips file)?

Tags: ios

My app is hanging on launch, I've turned on hang logging on the phone and have extracted a hang file (.ips file).

I want to find out what method from the app is referenced here:

```
  595  start + 2240 (dyld + 23940) [0x1c6e14d84]
  595  ??? (MyApp + 67912) [0x10204c948]
  595  UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIKitCore + 2273848) [0x1a513e238]
```

So I'm trying to use the  atos command to symbolicate it:

```
atos -arch arm64 -o MyApp.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp  -l
<what is the load address> 0x10204c948
```

But I don't know what to use for the load address. The Apple instructions for atos show how to find the load address from a .crash file, is it possible to find it from the .ips file?

```
    {"roots_installed":0,"ht_enablement_prefix":"HTThirdPartyDevSupport","bug_type":"328","app_name":"MyApp","app_cohort":"2|date=1707228000000&sf=143441&tid=4191156da0351f21056ec594160a49eddcf17997b909c7125a95adc8167d45d4&ttype=i","app_version":"16.1","timestamp":"2024-02-06 06:25:57.00 -0800","slice_uuid":"","adam_id":807625235,"build_version":"27","bundleID":"com.cequint.nameid.verizon","duration_ms":"9142","bug_subtype":"heavy","is_first_party":0,"share_with_app_devs":1,"os_version":"iPhone OS 17.4 (21E5184k)","incident_id":"18ED4F31-4578-4CDD-AC7C-33F090429E75","name":"MyApp","is_beta":1}
    Date/Time:        2024-02-06 06:25:16.495 -0800
    End time:         2024-02-06 06:25:25.638 -0800
    OS Version:       iPhone OS 17.4 (Build 21E5184k)
    Architecture:     arm64e
    Report Version:   47
    Incident Identifier: 18ED4F31-4578-4CDD-AC7C-33F090429E75
    
    Data Source:      KPerf Lightweight PET
    Shared Cache:     7D402D22-BB6B-3B47-9C63-90FAF8061A28 slid base address 0x19ab38000, slide 0x1ab38000 (System Primary)
    Shared Cache:     4A16245E-C114-3CD8-A848-490D27D024BB slid base address 0x197bbc000, slide 0x17bbc000 (DriverKit)
    Reason:           UIKit-runloop-MyApp: timeout 9096ms
    
    Command:          MyApp
    Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1103C615-0EC3-4E83-8393-305B9605CCA7/MyApp.app/MyApp
    Identifier:       com.cequint.nameid.verizon
    Version:          16.1 (27)
    Adam ID:          807625235
    Is First Party:   No
    Is Beta:          Yes
    Cohort:           2|date=1707228000000&sf=143441&tid=4191156da0351f21056ec594160a49eddcf17997b909c7125a95adc8167d45d4&ttype=i
    Architecture:     arm64
    Parent:           launchd [1]
    PID:              7665
    Time Since Fork:  0s
    
    Event:            Timed Out Runloop Hang
    Duration:         9.14s
    Duration Sampled: 9.13s
    Steps:            595 (10ms sampling interval)
    Report threshold: 1s
    
    Hardware model:   iPhone13,3
    Active cpus:      6
    HW page size:     16384
    VM page size:     16384
    
    Time Since Boot:  297009s
    Time Awake Since Boot: 69299s
    
    Total CPU Time:   14.177s (16.4G cycles, 23.3G instructions, 0.70c/i)
    Memory pressure:  average 58%, highest 60%
    Available memory: average 2536.58 MB, lowest 2375.36 MB
    I/O statistics:
      Overall:        3549 IOs (389 IOs/s), 20.83 MB (2339.21 KB/s)
      Tier0:          2604 IOs (286 IOs/s), 14.45 MB (1623.15 KB/s)
      Tier1:          753 IOs (83 IOs/s), 3612 KB (396.20 KB/s)
      Tier2:          192 IOs (21 IOs/s), 2916 KB (319.86 KB/s)
    Advisory levels:  Battery -> 3, User -> 3, ThermalPressure -> 0, Combined -> 3
    Free disk space:  97.09 GB/119.10 GB, low space threshold 150 MB
    Vnodes Available: 69.64% (16714/24000, 12000 allocated, 12000 soft limit)
    
    Preferred User Language: en-US
    Country Code:     US
    Keyboards:        en_US QWERTY
    OS Cryptex File Extents: 1
    
    Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
      595  start + 2240 (dyld + 23940) [0x1c6e14d84]
      595  ??? (MyApp + 67912) [0x10204c948]
      595  UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIKitCore + 2273848) [0x1a513e238]
      595  -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIKitCore + 2276348) [0x1a513ebfc]
      595  GSEventRunModal + 164 (GraphicsServices + 13536) [0x1e7c824e0]
      595  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CoreFoundation + 211304) [0x1a2cce968]
      595  __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CoreFoundation + 212360) [0x1a2cced88]
      595  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340 (CoreFoundation + 217272) [0x1a2cd00b8]
      595  __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CoreFoundation + 223400) [0x1a2cd18a8]
      595  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CoreFoundation + 226860) [0x1a2cd262c]
      595  -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28 (FrontBoardServices + 41812) [0x1bc0ea354]
      595  -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240 (FrontBoardServices + 42108) [0x1bc0ea47c]
      595  __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52 (FrontBoardServices + 42236) [0x1bc0ea4fc]
      595  _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 288 (libdispatch.dylib + 30828) [0x1aab8986c]
      595  _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (libdispatch.dylib + 15828) [0x1aab85dd4]
      595  __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352 (FrontBoardServices + 105564) [0x1bc0f9c5c]
      595  -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168 (FrontBoardServices + 57720) [0x1bc0ee178]
      595  __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108 + 280 (FrontBoardServices + 62796) [0x1bc0ef54c]
      595  -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 324 (FrontBoardServices + 63152) [0x1bc0ef6b0]
      595  -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288 (UIKitCore + 2419340) [0x1a5161a8c]
      595  -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 508 (UIKitCore + 2419956) [0x1a5161cf4]
      595  -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244 (UIKitCore + 1277752) [0x1a504af38]
      595  -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216 (UIKitCore + 1278152) [0x1a504b0c8]
      595  __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.226 + 612 (UIKitCore + 5018524) [0x1a53dc39c]
      595  -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316 (UIKitCore + 1281876) [0x1a504bf54]
      595  _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224 (UIKitCore + 1282724) [0x1a504c2a4]
      595  +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736 (UIKitCore + 1284636) [0x1a504ca1c]
      595  __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148 (UIKitCore + 1284884) [0x1a504cb14]
      595  -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 248 (UIKitCore + 1285188) [0x1a504cc44]
      595  -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 608 (UIKitCore + 1286876) [0x1a504d2dc]
      595  -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 332 (UIKitCore + 1292500) [0x1a504e8d4]
      595  __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216 (UIKitCore + 2172296) [0x1a5125588]
      595  _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112 (UIKitCore + 1622296) [0x1a509f118]
      595  __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke_2 + 108 (UIKitCore + 1622464) [0x1a509f1c0]
      595  -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 1240 (UIKitCore + 1624992) [0x1a509fba0]
      595  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92 (Foundation + 173344) [0x1a1b7c520]
      595  _CFXNotificationPost + 728 (CoreFoundation + 189960) [0x1a2cc9608]
      595  _CFXRegistrationPost + 440 (CoreFoundation + 192696) [0x1a2cca0b8]
      595  ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88 (CoreFoundation + 192880) [0x1a2cca170]
      595  __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148 (CoreFoundation + 194472) [0x1a2cca7a8]
      569  ??? (MyApp + 750216) [0x1020f3288]
      568  ??? (MyApp + 749776) [0x1020f30d0]
      554  ??? (MyApp + 811804) [0x10210231c]
      554  ??? (MyApp + 109676) [0x102056c6c]
      554  specialized withVaList<A>(_:_:) + 428 (Foundation + 5312064) [0x1a2062e40]
      554  _NSLogv + 164 (Foundation + 599648) [0x1a1be4660]
      554  _CFLogvEx3 + 252 (CoreFoundation + 652276) [0x1a2d3a3f4]
      554  _CFLogvEx2Predicate + 352 (CoreFoundation + 652792) [0x1a2d3a5f8]
      554  __CFLogCString + 84 (CoreFoundation + 652948) [0x1a2d3a694]
      554  _logToStderr + 144 (CoreFoundation + 653980) [0x1a2d3aa9c]
      554  __ulock_wait2 + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 59740) [0x1ebe8595c]
     *554  ??? (<30CE5ECC-BDD1-3D1F-B10E-75066730E6C5> + 5067480) [0xfffffff0082292d8]
    
    
    Process:          MyApp [7665]
    UUID:             2A34FFF7-B959-3717-81F5-6667D02778FD
    Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1103C615-0EC3-4E83-8393-305B9605CCA7/MyApp.app/MyApp
    Identifier:       com.cequint.nameid.verizon
    Version:          16.1 (27)
    Adam ID:          807625235
    Is First Party:   No
    Is Beta:          Yes
    Cohort:           2|date=1707228000000&sf=143441&tid=4191156da0351f21056ec594160a49eddcf17997b909c7125a95adc8167d45d4&ttype=i
    Shared Cache:     7D402D22-BB6B-3B47-9C63-90FAF8061A28 slid base address 0x19ab38000, slide 0x1ab38000 (System Primary)
    Architecture:     arm64
    Parent:           launchd [1]
    Footprint:        35.70 MB -> 39.17 MB (+3552 KB) (max 44.31 MB at time index 26)
    Pageins:          5 pages
    I/O:              1110 I/Os (4800 KB)
    Time Since Fork:  0s
    Num samples:      595 (1-595)
    CPU Time:         0.457s (1129.1M cycles, 3.0G instructions, 0.38c/i)
    Num threads:      24
    
      Thread 0x88813    DispatchQueue "com.apple.main-thread"(1),"com.apple.usernotifications.PKUserNotificationsRemoteNotificati"(253),"com.apple.usernotifications.UNUserNotificationServiceConnection"(227)    595 samples (1-595)    priority 35-41 (base 47)    cpu time 0.115s (311.7M cycles, 976.2M instructions, 0.32c/i)    76 I/Os (304 KB)
      595  start + 2240 (dyld + 23940) [0x1c6e14d84]
        595  ??? (MyApp + 67912) [0x10204c948]
          595  UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIKitCore + 2273848) [0x1a513e238]
            595  -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIKitCore + 2276348) [0x1a513ebfc]
<snip>
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447722/how-to-analyze-an-apps-ips-file-in-xcode

Comment: Can you try and renaming the `.ips` file to a `.crash` file? Open Xcode and go to `Window` -> `Devices & Simulators`. Connect any iOS device to your Mac (the device does not need to be the one that generated the IPS file). Access the "View Device Logs" button to open the Device Logs section, and drag and drop the renamed `.crash` file into this window. Right-click on the imported crash log and select "re-symbolicate log".

Comment: If you have the relevant dSYM files or xcarchive of the build that generated the IPS file, that process of re-symbolicating the log in Xcode could indirectly help you identify the load address by mapping the memory addresses in the IPS file to their corresponding symbols in your app's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load address is defined int the first line of the stack trace provided in the hang file. In this case, it is:

```
595  start + 2240 (dyld + 23940) [0x1c6e14d84]
```

The load address is the memory address of the start symbol in the dyld (dynamic linker) library. The offset from the start symbol is 2240.

So, the load address for your application (MyApp) would be:

```
0x1c6e14d84 - 2240 = 0x1c6e14c44
```

Now you can use this load address with the atos command to symbolicate the address `0x10204c948`:

```
atos -arch arm64 -o <PATH_OF_MyApp.dSYM>/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp -l 0x1c6e14c44 0x10204c948
```

Sometimes the outputs help me to identify the method causing the hang.